# Testing angular components: how can I test method call that comes after an async method call with expect(method).toHaveBeenCalledWith(p) in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test an async component method using jasmine. This method calls another private async component method and a service method afterwards. I wanna test the service method call but keep getting the error "

> expected `serviceMethod` to have been called with ... but it was never
> called

This is the component method I'm trying to test:

> ```
> public async componentMethodToTest(): Promise<void> {
>
>   await this.privateComponentMethod(param);
>
>   this.service.serviceMethod([
>   { key: 'str_1', value: 'val_1' },
>   { key: 'str_2', value: 'val_2' }
>   ]);
>
> }
> ```

What I have tried:

> ```
> describe('Component', () => {
>    let component: Component;
>    let fixture: ComponentFixture<Component>;
>
>    const mService = jasmine.createSpyObj('Service',
>     ['serviceMethod']);
>
> beforeEach(async(() => {
>    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
>        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
>        providers: [
>            { provide: Service, useValue: mService },
>        ]
>    })
>        .compileComponents();
> }));
> ```

> ```
> beforeEach(() => {
>   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
>   component = fixture.componentInstance;
>   fixture.detectChanges();
> });
> ```

> ```
> it('should do stuff', fakeAsync(() => {
>     mService.serviceMethod.and.callThrough();
>     const params =
>     [   
>         { key: 'str_1', value: 'val_1' },
>         { key: 'str_2', value: 'val_2' }
>     ]
>     component.componentMethodToTest();
>     tick();
>     fixture.detectChanges();
>     expect(mService.serviceMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params);
> }));
> ```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I am thinking you may need another `tick()` after the first one. In the test, right before the `expect(msService.serviceMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(params)` add a console.log of `doing assertion` and in the `componentToTest` method add a log of `calling service` right before the `this.service.serviceMethod` call. Ensure you see both logs and to make the test pass, make sure you see `calling service` before `doing assertion`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. In privateComponentMethod, there was another service async method call. I hadn't mocked the service nor spied on the service method. I mocked the service and the method as a Partial and let the method return a new resolved promise of the suitable type. I then spied on the method and let it return a promise.